# View is not loading after dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, webview

I have a webView in my firstViewController.
I'm letting the user change some arguments in the url in another viewController(secondViewController).

I'm presenting this second view controller to let the user do this.
When he is done (he is clicking the 'done' button and calling dismissViewControllerAnimated),
I would like to get the url-changes and load it to the view controllers webView. But the webView seems to not be loaded.... thats the problem.

Here's an example.

**firstViewController.h:**

```
.......
#import "SecondViewController.h"
.....
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
.....
```

**firstViewController.m:**

```
@synthesize webView;

SecondViewController *csvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];
csvc.OLDurlInWebView = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
csvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:csvc animated:YES completion:nil];
......
......
......
//I'm calling this method after dismissViewControllerAnimated from secondViewControllerClass
-(void)showInView:(NSString *)str {
    [self view];
    [self loadView];
    [self view];
    [self openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"TEST" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"TEST" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"TEST", nil];
    NSLog(@"current:%@ isLoaded:%d",webView.request.URL.absoluteString,self.isViewLoaded); //output 'current:(null) isLoaded:1'
    [sheet showInView:self.view];//this sheet test will not show, the app will crash:'Sheet can not be presented because the view is not in a window:.......'
}
-(void)openURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    NSLog(@"Trying to open %@ in webbrowser", url);

    [webView loadRequest:request];

}
```

**secondViewController.h:**

```
.......
#import "FirstController.h"
.......
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
NSString *OLDurlInWebView;
.......
}
.......
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *OLDurlInWebView;
- (IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender;
.......
```

**secondViewController.m:**

```
@synthesize OLDurlInWebView;

......
- (IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO/*YES*/ completion:nil]; //completion???
}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"SecondViewC didDisappear");
    WebViewController *wb = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"web"];

    NSString *newurl = @"http://facebook.com"; //let the user load facebook as example
    [wb view];
    [wb loadView]; //testing everything, nothing works
    [wb view];

    [wb performSelector:@selector(showInView:) withObject:newurl afterDelay:5];//the webView will not load after 5 seconds. Why?
}
```

Ok, from the beginning:

**In firstViewController:**

I'm presenting the secondviewcontroller.

**Now we are in secondViewController:**

The user will now change the url, but in this example, he will change the url to facebook.com.

Now we are going to send back this new url (facebook.com) to the firstViewController. The user 
clicks the doneButton and dismissViewControllerAnimated will be called.

**In attempt to get back to the firstViewController with this new url(facebook).**

I have tested everything I know, which is not enough. I have tested to call a normal function in firstViewController from secondViewController. The webView will not be able to load requests.

Then i tested to put the code in viewDidDisappear and giving the view 5 seconds to load, but it doesn't work.

I had this problem a time ago when the my app handles a URL Scheme Link in app delegate.
**- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url**
for example if you wan't to load another webView/label with a url or text from the URL scheme link?
how to do this from app delegate? this is the same problem as above.

What am I doing wrong/what do I dont know?
How to 'wait' for the view to load and then be able to load for example a webView with a url.?

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss has to be called on the first VC. You can do it from the second like so:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also, to get information back, you can use delegates, or a property in the first view:

Call before dismissing:

```
[self.presetingViewController setMyProperty:urlToPassBack];
```

Comment: setMyProperty would be a property on the presetingViewController. You would define it when you subclass UIViewController and then use that as the presenting viewController.